# Spring Batch - Chunk Oriented Processing without transactions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've been researching various batch frameworks and I appreciate the abstraction and out-of-the-box features such as skip, retry, listeners etc. that Spring Batch brings with it and I'm familiar with Spring framework so this is a natural choice.

However, the batch flows I intent to create do not have transactional databases on either end of the reader-process-write flow.  I desire to use Spring Batch to connect two systems through API's and still leverage the batch framework for tracking job executions and back the batch app with the Spring Batch database.

The remote API's support their own batching concepts, so, we can be sure to process 100 records and attempt to batch insert where the entire batch fails when one record is invalid.  In that way, I would still like Spring Batch to "rollback" and retry each record individually.

Is it possible to leverage Spring Batch with its backing batch metadata database, to use skip and retry, without holding database connections or using transactions during chunk based processing?

Edit:

Based on Mahmoud's comment, I can use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` with the `JobRepository` and a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` with the chunk steps.  So I will define a custom `StepBuilderFactory`:

```
@Component
public class MyStepBuilderFactory extends StepBuilderFactory {
  public MyStepBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    super(jobRepository, new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chunk-oriented tasklet requires a transaction manager to handle the "rollback" semantics you are looking for. If your step does not interact with a transactional resource, you can configure it to use a `ResourcelessTransactionManager`. This transaction manager is a NoOp implementation that can be used in such cases.

You can always use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` with the job repository to track job/step execution meta-data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So I'm going to define my own `StepBuilderFactory` that is configured with a `ResourcelessTransactionManager`, does that seem reasonable?  

Updated my question.

Comment: No need for that, the built-in StepBuilderFactory already allows you to specify which transaction manager to use at the step level: `stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").transactionManager(new ResourcelessTransactionManager())..`.